# Unable to use Ctrl+A+D to exit screen session of Termius

Tags: applications, linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Termius Android app on my phone to SSH connect my server. When I get in a screen session, it can't input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to leave this session, only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + one key can be input.

Also, my program in this session keeps running, so I can’t run any command unless using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop my program, but that is so stupid for just leaving a session！

Does anyone meet the same problem as me? It's much appreciated if anyone knows a solution.

Expected result:
Realize the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> effect in normal

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. According to a post on our sister site: [Unix.SE - Ctrl+a+d exiting terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22106/90391), Ctrl+D is the shortcut to end the session, regardless of Ctrl+A, but it has to be on an empty line. Perhaps you can experiment with it?

Comment: Not work for me, I think the problem is that Termius can not accept Ctrl+(2 keys). For example, when Ctrl was pressed, then pressing another key makes Ctrl reset. Therefore, It actually sends separately Ctrl+A and Ctrl+D into terminal, while the latter one just exit the connection.